# Using CSS or JS for Click-Expandable Text on Headlines Section of Angular App

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, expand

I have a section on the homepage of my Angular app where I'm displaying some stories with a headline and about two lines of opening content. What I'd like to do is provide that, with an "Expand" button at the end of the opening two lines that, when clicked, will cause the text space to expand to allow for the remainder of the text. I'd also want it toggle-able, so that the text can again be minimized by clicking on the same button.

Is there a way I can accomplish this with CSS/HTML alone? Or this best done via JavaScript -- or a combination of the two? I'm also wondering if Angular material has something out of the box to accomplish this kind of UI treatment. Perhaps an Expansion Panel (https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) could work? What does Google use for their own click-expandable stories in Google news (https://news.google.com)?

Overall, I'm looking for an elegant, simple solution that works with modern browsers. Also, note that this will be dynamic content, so it needs to be able to work by calculating the number of characters, or something like that, rather than by grouping the info in different div elements ahead of time.

Comment: You are better to use javascript for this, the closest you can get is :active selector of css

Comment: Do you want the "opening" and "closing" of the text space to be animated?

Comment: I'd prefer it to be a smooth transition, if possible without too much additional coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Angular you should do this the "angular" way.

We'll be using **CSS** and **Angular Animations**.

### [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hl5leq?embed=1&file=app/card/card.component.ts)

---

### Explanation:

Our component will be called `app-card` and by clicking on its header we'll show/hide the full contents of the card's "body".

> card.component.html

```
<div class="card-container">

  <div class="card-header" (click)="toggleFold()">
    I am the head of the card
  </div>

  <div class="card-body" [@panelState]="folded">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>

</div>
```

Key parts to note are the `toggleFold()` function that happens when we click the cards header, and the `@panelState` that binds the current state of our **card-body** depending on the `folded` property.

> card.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css'],
  animations : [
    // Here we are defining what are the states our panel can be in 
    // and the style each state corresponds to.
    trigger('panelState', [
      state('closed', style({ height: '32px', overflow: 'hidden' })),
      state('open', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('closed <=> open', animate('300ms ease-in-out')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class CardComponent {
  folded = 'closed';

  // toggleFold function simply changes our folded property
  // between "open" and "closed"
  toggleFold(){
    this.folded = this.folded === 'open' ? 'closed' : 'open';
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**

- In order to use angular animations you need to import the **"BrowserAnimationsModule"** from **"@angular/platform-browser/animations"** into your `app.module.ts`

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // <<
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent, 
    CardComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I REALLY like this approach and the end-result looks great. One note, I'm getting this error after adding the import for "animations": [ts] Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/animations'.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Using Angular 2.3.1

Comment: Will this work Angular 2.3.1? Seeing this issue: https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications/issues/209

Comment: Oh since **Angular v4.x** animations have been separated (like you can see here) and are imported a bit differently then in **v2.x**. In the older version you can import "animations, state, transition, style..." directly from **@angular/core**

Comment: This should do the job: `import { Component, OnInit, animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/core';` _(in the card.component.ts)_

Comment: Okay, got that. I am following through with the rest of this implementation now. Thanks for this @Mihailo!

Comment: Not a problem hope you manage to patch the differences. I strongly recommend you upgrade your application to the latest version of Angular. There are some really big improvements in performance and tooling. This [TOOL](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) should help you with the transition.

Comment: We do plan on upgrading. Unfortunately, despite what's advertised, in our particular app we're going to have to do a significant amount of re-coding to be able to move to Angular 4. We've already been looking into it.